# MVC - Binding dynamically added controls to a List<T> in a Model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-binding

**Using MVC 5 with a Razor (.cshtml) view**

You have a list of values in a model that needs to ultimately get data from a control in the view and append them to the list.

For example:

The **model** contains: `public List<string> value { get; set; }`

The List is allowed to contain up to 70 values, but can contain less.

In the **view** you have a button that dynamically adds `@Html.editorfor` fields, much like this: [image]

For each new field that is created, it's corresponding value must be appended to the `List<string> value`. So in this example,

The user clicks "Add Field", the new text box appears, and he enters "Line 1"

- When submitted, this field will post to the first index of the value list  like so: `value[0] = "Line 1"`

The user clicks "Add Field" again to add another value - he enters "Line 2"

- When submitted, this field will post to the second index of the value list like so: `value[1] = "Line 2"`

The User can add UP TO 70 fields (i.e He can click "add field" 65 times to add 65 values to the value list)

What would be the quickest and most efficient way to bind the data in this manner?

Comment: In your buttons `.click()` event, just dynamically add `<input type="text" name="value" />` to the DOM. You do not need indexers if the collection is a collection of `string` (or any other simple value type)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before you submit make sure those dynamically added inputs have correct model names and you should be fine. So in your example it would be something similar to this:

```
   <input type="text" name="value[0]" value="Line 1"/>
   <input type="text" name="value[1]" value="Line 2"/>
   <input type="text" name="value[3]" value="Line 3"/>
```

And the model binder will automatically create a List of `string` with those 3 strings ("Line 1","Line 2","Line 3") in them and assign it to the corresponding property, in this case, `value`.

EDIT: Here's how your addField function could look like to do just that:

```
 function addField(){
    var addedFieldCount=$('input.dynamic-field').length;
    if(addedFieldCount==70){//But you should check it on the server side too.
       alert('No more field allowed');
       return;
    }
    $('#fieldContainer').append('<input name="value['+addedFieldCount+']"/>');
 }
```

That's all. If you call it hard coding then go call it.

EDIT2: As Stephen Muecke noted, you do not need indexer when you're dealing with a collection of `string`. (I was not aware of that :)). So your function becomes even simpler:

```
 function addField(){
    var addedFieldCount=$('input.dynamic-field').length;
    if(addedFieldCount==70){//But you should check it on the server side too.
       alert('No more field allowed');
       return;
    }
    $('#fieldContainer').append('<input name="value"/>');
 }
```

Comment: Also you don't know how many fields the user wants to input, hence you won't know how many `<input type="text"/>` to put in the view

Comment: @Collateral.dmg, when I posted my answer, the OP hadn't provided any more information. He just needed to bind the values on the client side to the  model.

Comment: Also, if you want built-in model binding to match DOM input values to the model values you have to supply your request with inputs that have corresponding model names. And it's the job of client side to determine how to populate those inputs. And to put restriction on them, in this case to allow 70 inputs maximum, you can use client side or server side validation or combination of those two.

Comment: Note that you do not need to append the indexer because the property is just `List<string>` (and its better not to add them because it allows the flexibility to also delete textboxes)

Comment: My model values are always `null`. I think it is because my custom inputs don't have the attribute `value`. By default input element will not create the attribute `value` on its own. I can get the value with js/jQuery API, but model binding does not work. Any though on that?